# How make a local network to a wide network like internet?

Tags: network, cloud

I have a software that installed on computer number 1 (as a server with local address 192.168.1.11), so two other computers can work with it on a local network (a modem).
In other words, on two other computers we have a software that can work with computer number 1.
We can set on the software (computer number 2 and 3) to connect to which IP address (computer number 1).
My question is, what is the solution for connecting to the computer number 1 out of local network.
I mean, I want to work with software on my house as a remote.
The point is computer number 1 that has all the database can't be run on virtual server or somewhere else.
I need a virtual server, between computer 1 and two other computers to communicating with each other.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your "modem" is actually a Frankenstein Wi-Fi/Ethernet NAT/router/modem/switch/DHCP/DNS server box that is practically ubiquitous for small networks but it's often hard to isolate the functionality you actually need. Note that such consumer-grade hardware is explicitly off topic here.

All you need for a single IP subnet is a switch. Configure all host with a shared subnet and you're done.

An *internet* (lowercase i) is a connection between two or more networks, so minimally you'd need a second switch and a router in between or to connect 'elsewhere'. You can add more switches and more routers as required.

> what is the solution for connecting to the computer number 1 out of local network.

A router.

> I want to work with software on my house as a remote.

That sounds like you need a VPN connection over the Internet (capital I). Product recommendations are explicitly off topic here however.